# Processing time for F4 visa

Tags: usa, visa, family

I'm from Lebanon and my brother is a US Citizen. He applied for me for an F4 visa. My priority date was 21 October 2009 and to date I didn't get the visa. Could you advise the processing time and when it is expected for NVC to start processing my case?

Answer (score 1):

See each month's [visa bulletin](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/visa-law0/visa-bulletin.html). Currently visa numbers are available in the F4 category for people born in countries other than India, Mexico, or the Philippines for priority dates in 2004. You have about 5 more years to wait until a visa number is available for your priority date. NVC should start processing it soon before then.